# Using store.js to pass variables from one page to the next keeping the variable type intact

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have an input form which I am using to collect some information (graphics parameters), which is then used to define how the graphics on the next page will be rendered. The problem that I am having is that I am using store.js, which is supposed to work around the need for JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, but the variables that I am getting back are still strings.

Here is some of the code from the form:

FORM

```
<script src="../js/store.min.js"></script>

<form id="graphicsvars" method="Post" action="">

     <fieldset>
        <legend>Opacity</legend> 
        <p>Settings must be in the range 0 to 1.</p>
        <p>Maximum Opacity =  <input id="maxO" type="number" name="maxO"
        min="0" max="1" step=".01" value="1.0" ></p>
        <p>Minimum Opacity = <input id="minO" type="number" name="minO"
       min="0" max="1" step=".01" value="0.0"></p>
   </fieldset>

<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="pageSel()">    </p>
</form>

<script>
function pageSel() {
  alert("The data you have entered is now stored locally");
  window.open("test_sml2.html")
}  

var maxOpacity = document.getElementById("maxO").value
store.set("maxO", maxOpacity);
</script>
```

Here is the input test code:

```
<head>    
<script src="../js/store.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test Code</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Verifying input data</p>
    <p id="var1"></p>
<script>
    var mxO = store.get("maxO");
        alert( typeof mxO );
    document.getElementById("var1").innerHTML = mxO;

</script>
```

The alert tells me that mxO is a string. the graphics page is expecting this value to be a number. I'd appreciate if anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Why don't you want to use JSON.parse?

Comment: store.js will be storing the object as a string either way.

Comment: I think I will have to try it, thanks.